# How can I pass an array in throw new Exception() in PHP. What is the best possible away to pass an array in exception handler?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, exceptionhandler

Here is my code but its send me error. Its said Wrong parameters for Exception handler.

```
   try {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email_address' => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20',
            'phone_number' => 'alpha_num|max:13',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:18',
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new Exception('Please checkout your fields again!', $validator->errors() );
        }

    }catch( Exception $e){
        return ['success'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()];
    }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to throw a bunch of errors for each invalid item in your validation?

Comment: I am trying to throw array values from exception for checking which field is invalid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which will join the array as a string

something like this:

```
try {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email_address' => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20',
            'phone_number' => 'alpha_num|max:13',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:18',
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new Exception('Please checkout your fields again!', implode(',',$validator->errors()) );
        }

    }catch( Exception $e){
        return ['success'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this may be more help for you:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email_address' => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20',
            'phone_number' => 'alpha_num|max:13',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:18',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('yourRoute')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

For more details, you can follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators).

Comment: But I don't want to redirect. It should be return as json data from API end point.